# How do I catch when UIViewController displays after dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c

I've got two `UIViewControllers`. I'm using modal segue to the second one, when coming back I use `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. I want to fire a method when I come back to the first one. How can I do that?

I tried to fire a custom notification before `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and catching it in the first `UIViewController`, but it doesn't catch anything, because it's still on the second one when it's fired.

Comment: So, you don't want to show the first view controller again ?

Comment: Sure I want to show the first view controller back again, but when it shows, I want to fire a method in that first view controller so I need something like UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification but for coming back from modal segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easy options I can see.

Use the `viewDidDisappear:` method in the view you're dismissing.

`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method accepts a block that actually executes after `viewDidDisappear` executes in the dismissing view.

---

To pass a reference from one view controller to the next:

In the second view controller's `.h` file, add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) FirstViewController *firstVC;
```

In your first view controller, add the following method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([@"segue_YOUR_SEGUE_NAME" isEqualToString:[segue identifier]]) {
        if([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:
            [SecondViewController class]]) {

            SecondViewController *dest = (SecondViewController*)[segue
                destinationViewController];
            dest.firstVC = self;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your second view controller, you can do two things, as I already stated:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                         completion:^{
                             [self.firstVC someMethod];
                         }];
```

OR...

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.firstVC someMethod];
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I want that method to be executed within the first UIViewController, not the second one.

Comment: So have the first view controller pass a reference to the second view controller when it presents it?

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand each other or maybe I asked a wrong question. First UIViewController loads up, I click a button, using modal segue Second UIViewController shows up, I click a button on the Second one and it hides. When it hides and First one shows up again, I want to change something in this First UIViewController using a method that I want to fire right in the moment it shows up. Why would I then pass a reference to the Second one if I don't want to change any information between these two. OR maybe I don't understand what you mean by passing a reference to the second controller

Comment: When the first one presents the second one, it can pass a reference to itself to the second one.  The second one hangs on to this reference until it's time for it to hide, at which point it uses this reference to the first view controller to call a method on the first view controller.

Comment: That sounds like a simple solution, but I guess it's not as easy as it sounds, how do I do that?